# JavaScript RGB string (`rgb(r, g, b)`) to HEX (`#rrggbb`) conversion

Tags: javascript, hex, rgb, color-scheme, color-conversion

The `componentToHex` function works well for the first component `r`, but for the other two components, `g` and `b`, it doesn't work as expected:

```js
let componentToHex = (val) => {
  const a = val.toString(16);
  return a.length === 1 ? "0" + a : a;
};

let rgbToHex = (rgb) => {
  const hex = rgb.replace("rgb(", "").replace(")", "").split(",");
  const r = hex[0];
  const g = hex[1];
  const b = hex[2];

  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

console.log(rgbToHex ('rgb(1,255,148)'));
```

Comment: `val` is a string value. You have to convert it to a number first, otherwise `toString(16)` won't convert it to a hex value (it will just return the value as is).

Comment: maybe because you pass val to componentToHex as a string and not as number?

Answer (score 1):

You want the number part (the `val`) to be a *number* before you call `toString` on it. If it's a *string* when you call `toString` on it, it'll remain as-is:

```js
let componentToHex = (val) => {
  const a = Number(val).toString(16);
  //        ^^^^^^^^^^^
  return a.length === 1 ? "0" + a : a;
}
let rgbtohex = (rgb) => {
  return '#' + rgb
    .match(/\d+/g)
    .map(componentToHex)
    .join('');
}


console.log(rgbtohex('rgb(1,255,148)'));
```

Also note that you should always declare variables before using them (else errors will be thrown in strict mode, or they'll be implicitly global, which can cause bugs).

As you can see above, the function that takes and transforms the input numbers can be made more elegant by matching digit characters, mapping to `componentToHex`, and then joining.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to convert the components to `number`, so you are passing them as `string` to `componentToHex`, which expects a `number`.

As [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) will give you 3 `string`s in this case, you can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number) to easily parse all 3:

```js
function componentToHex(c) {
  // This expects `c` to be a number:
  const hex = c.toString(16);

  return hex.length === 1 ? `0${ hex }` : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(rgb) {
  // .map(Number) will convert each string to number:
  const [r, g, b] = rgb.replace('rgb(', '').replace(')', '').split(',').map(Number);
  
  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}


console.log(rgbToHex('rgb(1,255,148)'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
let componentToHex = (val) => {
  a = Number(val).toString(16);
  return a.padStart(2, '0');
};

let rgbtohex = (rgb) => {
  hex = rgb.slice(4, -1).split(',');
  return hex.reduce((a, b) => a + componentToHex(b), '#');
};

rgbtohex('rgb(1,255,148)');
```

(Modified it to make shorter)